# Error when JBoss starts: address already in use

Tags: java, netbeans, jboss, jboss7.x

I have a problem when I want to start my JBoss server. I'm working on Netbeans and I added my server with `Server > Add Server > JBoss Application Server`.

I configured my server with the port `8181` because the port `8080` is already in use. But when I start it, it fails because it's trying to connect to the port `8080`:

> 10:10:48,071 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread
>   1-5) MSC00001: **Failed to start service** jboss.web.connector.http:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.web.connector.http: JBAS018007:
>
> Error starting web connector   at
>   org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:271)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
>
> Caused by: LifecycleException:  L'initialisation du
>   gestionnaire de protocole a échoué: java.net.BindException: **Address
>   already in use: JVM_Bind /127.0.0.1:8080**    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:985)  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:267)
>     ... 5 more

I'm using JDK 1.7. My environnment variables are well configured: `JAVA_HOME = path/to/jdk1.7`. And in Netbeans, in the properties of the server, my Java Platform is JDK 1.7.

Here is the beginning of the log to check the values:

> Calling "C:\Server\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
>   "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings
>
> ## with values: -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
>
> JBoss Bootstrap Environment
>
> JBOSS_HOME: C:\Server\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final
>
> JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java
>
> JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat
>   -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: "*I configured my server with the port 8181*" => how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your `standalone.xml` in directory `$JBOSS_HOME$/standalone/configuration` and check the element

```
<socket-binding name="http" port="XXXX"/>
```

Does XXXX equal `8181` or `8080`? I'm betting it's `8080`. Change it to `8181` and restart JBoss.

Comment: Thanks, I did. But I still have an error : **Address already in use: bind**. Do you think there is an other variable to change ?

Comment: And when I check with netstat, there is no port 8181 in use :/

Comment: Well, when I go to localhost:8181, I don't have any error. But in the log, I still have those exception. And when I do a netstat, the port 8181 is used. So I assume that it's working.

Comment: It happens that JVM still has a running instance. Have you tried to kill all running JVM instances before starting JBoss? You may have started the JBoss instance before (in another console).

Answer (score 5):

If you are not sure which process is blocking your port (if you deploy your application to an unknown server this happens from time to time) you really want to have a look at the `netstat.exe` tool (part of windows):

```
cmd -> "netstat -o"
```

This will show you each port in use with the `Pid` (Process ID) using it. With this ID you can see in the taskmanager which Process is blocking your port.

`Netstat` also has some other handy options.

Comment: Thanks but I know that the port is already used by my Tomcat. And when I try to start with an other port (like @TT. said), the port 8181 (that I choose) isn't in the list of "netstat".

Comment: @TT thanks for editing... this all lower case is always a pain for germans ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Check your standalone.xml:
And check two ports:
`<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}"> &
<socket-binding name="http" port="9090"/>`

Offset should be 0 if you have set your http port on 9090.

Answer (score 0):

for me I have changed in intellij File -> Settings -> Debugger ( Built-in Server) port to something else (other than 8080) as shown in the

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Run this in command prompt to check if there is a task running:

```
netstat -ano | findstr {your_port}
```

If there is, you will be able to see task id, and then run the following ro remove the task running:

```
taskkill /F /pid {task_id}
```

If you see nothing as output, that means that there is nothing running, and it should work.

Hope this helps.